Match a string from a list of wildcard patterns
There is a list of wildcard patterns (ab*, *ab*, *a?, ???, ...) and I query this list with abc (queries do not have wildcards). The output should be true since ab*, *ab* and ??? patterns in the list match abc. If none of the patterns match, as in case of wxyz the output should be false.
The brute force way of achieving this is to iterate through the list of patterns and check if any of them match the input query. The time complexity of this approach would be O(num_patterns * num_chars_in_pattern * num_char_in_query).

Is there a better data structure to solve this problem? I had thought of trie but I found traversing a trie of wildcards is a difficult task (should eat character or should go down in *?).
Is there pre-built solution to this problem? Like a datastore which already provides this feature. I had checked redis and elasticsearch but seems they don't provide this feature of searching in a list of wildcard patterns. The instead provide the feature of searching a wildcard/regex in a list of "normal" strings (strings with no wildcards).

Input Constraints:

List of wildcard patterns = 10^6
Average size of a wildcard pattern = 10^2
Average size of a input query = 10^3

Output SLA: <=100 ms

In the real world you'd probably just use regex e.g. in python re.fullmatch('|'.join(map(lambda s:s.replace('*', '.*').replace('?', '.'), ['ab*', '*ab*', '*a?', '???'])), 'abc')

I think the time complexity of this is O(n*m) where n=size of input string and m=size of regex pattern. If there are t regexes in my list, then the time complexity becomes O(n*m*t). This was what I was referring to as brute force approach but it goes well above the sla. n*m*t=10^11. I think 10^8 ops take 1s in an average cpu (please correct me if I am wrong here). So that's 1000 seconds (way above 100ms)

Agreed, this approach is not the most optimal, but will be perfectly fine in most applications. Just not in coding contests :)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-pattern-matching/
